# How do I fix/debug a "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error?

Tags: c

I'm very new to coding. I'm trying to make a simple math equation making use of float, using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int car() {

int r1;
int m1;
int m2;
 
float lift_a_car(const int r1, const int m1, const int m2);

lift_a_car = r1 + (2 * m1 / (m1 + m2));

printf("%.4f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));

return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run it, I get this error:

```
arrays.c:12:12: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   12 | lift_a_car = r1 + (2 * m1 / (m1 + m2));
```

I couldn't find a good explanation for this error anywhere. Can someone please explain this error to me? And is there any way to simplify/improve this code overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// functions shall be defined here
float lift_a_car(int r1, int m1, int m2)
{
    // note to get a float result, you need to cast to float
    return (r1 + (2 * (float)m1 / (m1 + m2)));
}

int main() {
    // Here you can call the function
    printf("%.4f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`lift_a_car` is a function and you cannot assign to a function in C. If you wanted to **define** a function, you should specify a function body using curly braces:

```
float lift_a_car(const int r1, const int m1, const int m2)
{
    return r1 + (2 * m1 / (m1 + m2));
}
```

Note that you cannot define a function inside of another function in C, so your `lift_a_car` function must be defined outside and before your `car` function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create a function `lift_a_car`. It must be outside of `int car` as nested functions are not supported. Functions must be top-level entities in C, not within any scope (`{}`). (In your code, `lift_a_car` is inside `car`). And the name of the entry-point function must be `main`. Since your `car` function returns `0`, it seems like you are trying to use `car` instead of the name `main` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float lift_a_car(const int r1, const int m1, const int m2)
{
    float result = r1 + (2 * m1 / (m1 + m2));
    return result;
}


int main() 
{

    int r1 = 2;
    int m1 = 80;
    int m2 = 1400;
 
    printf("%.4f\n", lift_a_car(r1, m1, m2));

   return 0;
}
```

Also, since you are performing division with two integers, the decimal points will be truncated, so cast one of the values first to `float` to retain the decimal points:

```
float lift_a_car(const int r1, const int m1, const int m2)
{
    float result = r1 + ((float) 2 * m1 / (m1 + m2));
    return result;
}
```

We could try to help more if you provide more details about what you are trying to do.